# How to resolve Unrecognized option: -Xquickstart error in WAS Liberty 8.5.5

Tags: java-8, websphere-liberty, java-6

We are upgrading our web application that uses Spring3 MVC, from WAS 6.1 to WAS liberty profile 8.5.5.Please find the server.env config file as below:

Mentioning the specific JRE

**JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_38**

When i tried starting the server, i am getting the below exception during the application start.

**Could not create the Java virtual machine.
Unrecognized option: -Xquickstart**

So we added the below code in the server.env

#Temporary fix for eliminating error

**WLP_SKIP_MAXPERMSIZE=true**

The issue we are facing now is, the server starts good when we Debug and throws Error when we start it.

Please anyone tell me what needs to be done to resolve this error.

Thanks.

Comment: Afaik, HotSpot doesn’t have an option `-Xquickstart`. Google suggests that this is an option specific to IBM’s JVM.

Comment: First of all JDK 1.6 is no longer supported by anybody, also Liberty 8.5.5 is very, very old. Download the latest Libery 18.0.0.2 with bundled IBM Java 8 and use that for your migration.

Comment: Thanks all for sharing the knowledge.